# How to remotely log into google account?

Tags: google, lost-phone

I lost my phone and the person who found it, logged out of my google account. Is there a way to make my devive log into google account? (so that i can use "find my phone" to find it.)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but if the Google account has been removed from the phone it is now no longer related to you.

That is the reason you should protect your phone at least with a PIN code. Then your Google account can't be removed from the device that easily. Of course a factory reset can still be performed but then the "finder" of your device runs into the Factory reset Protection (FRP).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.